# How to create custom meta tags in Vue Meta 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-meta

I am using `Vue Meta 3` to provide meta data to the website. The API for this is [here](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/packages/useMeta)

I do not understand how to provide custom meta tags( e.g Open Graph tags such as `og:type`). This is what I have tried to do in a component:

```
setup() {
    useMeta({
      title: "Homepage",
      meta: [
          {name: "hunky:dory", content: "website"}
      ],
      description: "This is the homepage."
    })
  },
```

The HTML that gets outputted ends up like this:

```
<head>
 <title>Homepage</title>
 <meta name="description" content="This is the homepage.">
 <meta name="meta" content="website"> <!-- should be <meta name="hunky:dory content="website"> -->
</head>
```

If I change the code to this:

```
setup() {
    useMeta({
      title: "Homepage",
      "hunky:dory": [
          {content: "website"}
      ],
      description: "This is the homepage."
    })
  },
```

I get illegal HTML output:

```
<head>
     <title>Homepage</title>
     <meta name="description" content="This is the homepage.">
     <hunky:dory>website</hunky:dory> <!-- total nonsense -->
    </head>
```

How do I get the output to be:

```
<head>
         <title>Homepage</title>
         <meta name="description" content="This is the homepage.">
         <meta name="hunky:dory" content="website">
        </head>
```

Comment: UPDATE: I dropped vue-meta and went for @vueuse/head https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vueuse/head package instead. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 parts to getting og meta working -- I think I can help with part 1:

1. Correct `vue-meta` syntax
2. Server-Side Rendering (SSR)

#### Part 1: vue-meta for Vue 3

I wrote this with `vue-class-component`, and it seems to be working:

```js
meta = setup(() => useMeta(computed(() => ({
  title: this.event?.name ?? 'Event not found',
  og: {
    image: this.event?.bannerUrl ?? 'http://yourwebsite.com/images/default-banner.png'
  }
}))))
```

...which presumably translates to this in vanilla Vue 3:

```js
setup() {  
  useMeta(
    computed(() => ({
      title: this.event?.name ?? 'Event not found',
      og: {
        image: this.event?.bannerUrl ?? 'http://yourwebsite.com/images/default-banner.png'
      }
    }))
  )
}
```

Result:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cloudstorage.com/images/event-123.png">
```

References:

- [GitHub -> vue-meta@next -> example for vue-router](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next/examples/vue-router)
- [Also hinted in the readme](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next#:%7E:text=og%3A)

#### Part 2: SSR

Once I'd done part 1, I realized that I hadn't setup SSR... so I'm only rendering the meta for my users, not for Facebook's crawler (not very useful). I'm afraid I haven't fixed this yet on my project; **perhaps someone else can pitch in that part!**

Until then, maybe this will get you started:

- [SSR options](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/ssr.html)
- [Vue 3's native SSR](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/ssr/introduction.html)
- [Note on SSR in the `vue-meta` readme](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta/tree/next#ssr)

Note: `vue-meta` is under the `Nuxt` GitHub organization => **you might consider migrating to Nuxt v3** (which is built on top of Vue):

- [Nuxt v3 tracker issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5708)
- [Slides suggesting beta this month (June 2021)](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1cWxCe9IZVRzM2W4OqvA4PtBr9_GLcF3n7VJEUoBLjg8/edit#slide=id.gbe7ff63d62_0_1443).

Comment: I don't use Nuxt, or Vue-Cli. I prefer to have full control over the application because then you can update/upgrade parts as you wish.

Comment: @volumeone - How do you build your app for production?

Comment: Using Webpack 5. It is a Node.js/Express backend with Vue.js 3 front-end. All gets put through Webpack.

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond me for now. I think your best bet might be to open a new question that specifically targets "Building Vue 3 with SSR and webpack 5".

Comment: Feel free to leave the question open -- maybe someone else can add a more SSR-specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but maybe not useless for anyone facing issues with Vue 3 (and vue-meta). With the below detailed woraround, you are not dependent on any 3rd party lib.

My project is currently in development stage in local environment (so not fully tested), but a probable workaround is using **[beforeCreate](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforecreate)** lifecycle hook for adding meta tags if you are using **Options API** in **Vue 3** (with vue-router), **SFC way** (e.g. If you are using single-file-component views for *"pages"* and you want them all to have their custom meta info).

In the hook method you can create DOM nodes and append them to the head like:

```
...
beforeCreate(){
  // adding title for current view/page using vue-i18n
  let title = document.createElement(`TITLE`)
  title.innerText = this.$t(`something`)

  document.querySelector(`head`).appendChild(title)

  // adding og:image
  let ogImage = document.createElement(`META`)
  ogImage.setAttribute(`name`,`og:image`)
  ogImage.setAttribute(`content`,`YOUR-IMAGE-URL`)

  document.querySelector(`head`).appendChild(ogImage)
}
...
```

I'm not sure yet if this is an efficient way to make it work, but gonna try to update this post when the project is in production.

I have tested this solution with chrome plugins like this one:
[Localhost Open Graph Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localhost-open-graph-debu/kckjjmiilgndeaohcljonedmledlnkij)

Comment: I went with vueuse/head instead npmjs.com/package/@vueuse/head

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues then I came across this which solves the problem for me.
Here is the link to the original post: [vue3 vue-meta showing name="meta"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72095078/in-vue3-vue-meta-showing-name-meta-for-each-meta-tags-so-not-able-to-add-twit)

> In vue js 3 you should use the vue3-meta or alpha version. Then do the
> following
>
> ```
> metaInfo() {
>     return {
>         htmlAttrs: { lang: 'en', amp: true },
>         title: "page title",
>         description : "Page description",
>         twitter: {
>             title: "twitter title",
>             description: "twitter description",
>             card: "twitter card",
>             image: "twitter image",
>         },
>         og: {
>             title : 'og title!',
>             description : 'og description!',
>             type : 'og type',
>             url : 'og url',
>             image : 'og image',
>             site_name : 'og site name',
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> if you want to use meta name then change the config in main.js
>
> ```
> import { createMetaManager, defaultConfig, plugin as metaPlugin } from 'vue-meta'
> const metaManager = createMetaManager(false, {
>     ...defaultConfig,
>     meta: { tag: 'meta', nameless: true },
> });
> ```
>
> and in your component use the meta name below
>
> ```
> metaInfo() {
>     return {
>         meta: [
>             {'name' : 'author', 'content' : 'author'},
>             { name: 'description', content: 'authors' },
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```